# How to implement pause and resume countdowntimer?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have Implemented a countdowntimer in my application.it's working fine.Now i implemented a quit button in my app with dialog box permission (yes or no).when user press yes then quit and no back to game.Now my problem is how to pause the Countdowntimer when i click on quit button and resume on no button in dialog box.

**Here is my code:-**

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private Question currentQ;
    private GamePlay currentGame;
    public CountDownTimer counterTimer;
    private Button nextBtn1, nextBtn2, nextBtn3, nextBtn4, nextBtn5;


            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.question);
                processScreen();
         }
                /**
         * Configure current game and get question
         */
         private void processScreen()
         {
        currentGame = ((Application)getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
        currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();
        nextBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        nextBtn1.setEnabled(true);
        nextBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        nextBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        nextBtn2.setEnabled(true);
        nextBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        nextBtn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        nextBtn3.setEnabled(true);
        nextBtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        nextBtn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        nextBtn4.setEnabled(true);
        nextBtn4.setOnClickListener(this);
        nextBtn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer5);
        nextBtn5.setEnabled(true);
        nextBtn5.setOnClickListener(this);
        /**
         * Update the question and answer options..
         */
        setQuestions();

    }

     /**
     * Method to set the text for the question and answers from the current games
     * current question
     */
    private void setQuestions() {
        //set the question text from current question
        String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion());
        TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        qText.setText(question);
         //set the available options
        List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
        TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        option1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));
        TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        option2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));
        TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        option3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));
        TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        option4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));
        int score = currentGame.getScore();
        String scr = String.valueOf(score);
        TextView score1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        score1.setText(scr);

        counterTimer = new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {
        public void onFinish() {                
                if(currentGame.getRound()==20)
                {
                nextBtn1.setEnabled(false);
                nextBtn2.setEnabled(false);
                nextBtn3.setEnabled(false);
                nextBtn4.setEnabled(false);
                nextBtn5.setEnabled(false);
                final Handler handle = new Handler();
                Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Time's Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                };
                handle.postDelayed(delay,3000);
                }

                else if(currentGame.getRound()==0)
                {
                currentGame.decrementScore();
                final Handler handle = new Handler();
                Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        processScreen();
                    }
                };
                handle.postDelayed(delay,3000);
                }

                else if(currentGame.getRound()==19)
                {
                        nextBtn1.setEnabled(false);
                        nextBtn2.setEnabled(false);
                        nextBtn3.setEnabled(false);
                        nextBtn4.setEnabled(false);
                        nextBtn5.setEnabled(false);
                        currentGame.decrementScore();
                        final Handler handle = new Handler();
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Time's Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                processScreen();
                            }
                        };
                        handle.postDelayed(delay,3000);
                 }
            }

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);
                time.setText( ""+millisUntilFinished/1000);
                                }
        };
        counterTimer.start();
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        nextBtn1.setEnabled(false);
        nextBtn2.setEnabled(false);
        nextBtn3.setEnabled(false);
        nextBtn4.setEnabled(false);
        nextBtn5.setEnabled(false);
        arg0.setEnabled(true);
        //Log.d("Questions", "Moving to next question");
        if(arg0.getId()==R.id.answer5)
        {       
            Button yes, no;
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.FullHeightDialog); //this is a reference to the style above
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog1); //I saved the xml file above as yesnomessage.xml
            dialog.setCancelable(true);

            //to set the message
            TextView message =(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvmessagedialogtext);
            message.setText("Are you sure you want to Exit?");
            yes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bmessageDialogYes);
            yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
             counterTimer.cancel();
             finish();
             startActivity(new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, SplashActivity.class));             
             }
                        });

             no = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bmessageDialogNo);
             no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v)  
             {
             dialog.dismiss();
             nextBtn1.setEnabled(true);
             nextBtn2.setEnabled(true);
             nextBtn3.setEnabled(true);
             nextBtn4.setEnabled(true);
             }
                        });
             dialog.show();
    }

        else
        {
            if(!checkAnswer(arg0)) return;  

        /**
         * check if end of game
         */
        if (currentGame.isGameOver()){
            //Log.d("Questions", "End of game! lets add up the scores..");
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Correct: " + currentGame.getRight());
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Wrong: " + currentGame.getWrong());
            final Handler handle = new Handler();
            Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, EndgameActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            };
            handle.postDelayed(delay,2000);

        }
            else
            {
                final Handler handle = new Handler();
                Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                   startActivity(new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, QuestionActivity.class));
                   finish();
                    }
                };
                handle.postDelayed(delay,2000);
                      }
                  }
              }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        switch (keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    /**
     * Check if a checkbox has been selected, and if it
     * has then check if its correct and update gamescore
     */
    private boolean checkAnswer(View v) {
        final Button b = (Button) v;
        String answer = b.getText().toString();
         counterTimer.cancel();
         b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ans);
         b.setEnabled(false);
        //Log.d("Questions", "Valid Checkbox selection made - check if correct");
            if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
                {
                b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ansgreen);
                //Log.d("Questions", "Correct Answer!");
                Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Correct Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                currentGame.incrementScore();
                }

            else{
                b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ansred);
                //Log.d("Questions", "Incorrect Answer!");
                Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Incorrect Answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                currentGame.decrementScore1();
                            }
            return true;
        }

    public void show() 
    {
    counterTimer.cancel();          
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess yu can do this by making an static variable which will preserve your timer value on click of quit button and you can go forward with this value on click of no button. So simple.

Comment: can you help me with some code.

Comment: Hey! I have told you a very simple method. you can do it on your own dude. I don't think you'll need my help in code part too. Come on give it a try.

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738362/pause-countdowntimer-in-android-when-activity-is-not-in-front)

Comment: @Chandan check my answer and merge with your code..

Comment: @Chandan it is working demo, first create a demo app and check after that implement in your code.

Comment: @ManishSrivastava Thank's for your response.but i already done lot of R&D on Countdown timer.But I Don't understand why my timer is not get paused on dialog box Popup .

Comment: have you check my code? its working man..

Comment: @ManishSrivastava Yeah!!i have checked your code but if you see my code i have implemented countdowntimer .i just having problem in call on my no button on dialog box.

Comment: @Chandan I don't know about your code what you have did there, but mine is working fine if you want that demo project I can mail you. Just put your email id on my blog.

Comment: @ManishSrivastava I send you msg in google.hope you receive .