# How to pause the timer after a fixed time

Tags: android, timer

in my application i have a timer.i want the timer to get paused by itself after 60 secs.can any one help me out..this is what i have done

```
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
         mins = secs / 60;

        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
        /*timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));*/

        timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", secs) );
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);



    }

};
```

Comment: you need to stop remember the old value and re run again with the old value when required

Comment: you can not pause timer instead do as @Raghunandan says

Answer (score 1):

Use CountDownTimerwithPause class to pause and resume the timer. refere this

[Pause CountDownTimer in Android when activity is not in front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738362/pause-countdowntimer-in-android-when-activity-is-not-in-front)

override onTick method of it.when timmer reaches 60000 call pause() with timer object.

Answer (score 0):

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            startCountDownTimer();


        }
    });
```

protected void startCountDownTimer() {

```
         cdTimer = new CountDownTimer(total, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    //update total with the remaining time left
                    total = millisUntilFinished;
                    tv.setText("seconds remaining: " +  millisUntilFinished/ 1000);
                }
                public void onFinish() {
                    tv.setText("done!");
                }
            }.start();
    }
```